# GoogleMap complains of being a null object reference

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I am working on an android application where I use maps and this is the error that I am getting

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.setMapType(int)' on a null object reference
```

Prior to posting my query here I have looked for other similar issues but my code already have all what is being suggested so I was hoping if someone could point out the error.

This is the line which throws the error(second line).
I have no idea why it is caling map null when I've assigned it (at least I think I have)

```
private void initViews() {
    map = ((SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    //map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
}
```

and also this is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="65dp" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [getMapAsync(...)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment.html#getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback)) instead of getMap(). 
Example can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/?hl=en).